# IP headers in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, ip

I am testing the behaviour of some client software, and need to write some software that emulates router-like functionality, preferably using something simple like UDP sockets. All it needs to do is receive the packet, alter the time to live, and send it back. Is this possible in regular Java? Or do you do something like the following:

1. Listen on Socket A
2. For EACH udp packet received, open a NEW socket, set time to live on that socket, and send it back (or this isn't possible/efficient?)
3. Receiver gets packet with altered values that appear like it has traversed some hops (but in reality hasn't)

So two approaches may be possible - editing the recieved packet directly (and then simply sending back), or constructing a new packet, copying the values from the original one and setting the appropriate headers/socket options before sending it out.

**EDIT**: the 'router' does not do any complex routing at all such as forwarding to other routers... it is simply decrements the t-t-l header field of the received message and sends the message directly back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer API of Socket and ServerSocket class. Most of the server implementation for variety of protocols does accept packets at standard port like 80 and send response using some ephemaral port.

Comment: Please refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86387/Implementing-a-Web-Server-in-Java

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the CodeProject article is for a simple web server. I am looking to make a very very basic emulation of a router, in that it receives a message, makes small changes, and sends it back to the sender.

Comment: Here is the open source implementing of AODV routing protocol. I have used it and it worked really great in my routing implementation. It has full TCP/IP protocol stack implementation. Let's see how it works for you. http://jist.ece.cornell.edu/docs/040421-swans-aodv.pdf

Comment: If that is too complex to use for you then see a simple example which I found online at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/RouterPatterninJava.htm

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, I'd like to be clear: I am looking for something simple in UDP sockets. Client opens socket to Router and sends UDP datagram. Server receives UDP datagram, modifies IP header t-t-l value etc, sends UDP datagram right back to Client. Not RMI, or implementation of other routing protocols. It literally returns the datagram to the sender with ttl changed like a real hop on the internet. No other complex routing (like forwarding to another router) right now.

Comment: I would suggest to go through the API and source code of SWANSimplementation. It's based on sockets. It has capabilities to specify transport layer protocol like TCP or UDP. Also it has routing table mechanism in its implementation. I think you can specify TTL for incoming packets but you need to check it. You can start at http://jist.ece.cornell.edu/. Just so you know it's simulator but you will get an idea of your implementation from its source code. Even you should be able to modify their source code as its open source.